# Inconsistently getting "Exception has occurred: JavascriptException" error selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

Hello something really weird happening I'm getting
"Exception has occurred: JavascriptException / Message: javascript error: this.each is not a function" on this specific line:

```
waiting.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "xxxx")))
```

it does work half of the time but at the other half gives this error

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import requests
from cgitb import text
from unittest import result
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.get("https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/M4A4%20%7C%20Mainframe%20%28Minimal%20Wear%29")

waiting = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
waiting.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "csgofloat-itemfloat")))

page_source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, "html.parser")
hopefully_floats = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "csgofloat-itemfloat"})

time.sleep(15)
print(hopefully_floats)
print(type(hopefully_floats))
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducible example, including error trace and the url of that page.

Comment: @platipus_on_fire ty for your respond I editted here is the code there is also a extension I can also write if it is necessary, class name is related with extension

Comment: There is no such class in that page' html. What items are you looking for exactly? The price of the items?

Comment: it was an element that extension shows the extension is: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/csgofloat-market-checker/jjicbefpemnphinccgikpdaagjebbnhg?hl=en

Comment: I am more confused now: what is your ultimate goal? What information are you looking for, from that page? Ignore whatever extension you are using, concentrate on the actual page elements: what info are you looking for?

Comment: printing https://snipboard.io/JZNDRi.jpg the value on the screenshot which can be seen by extension

Comment: @jetrldz did you look into https://csgofloat.com/api/v1/listings ? You may not need selenium, that api is scrapable with requests, it doesn't necessarily require an API key, it's (obviously) free, and you avoid the overheads of selenium and other extensions. Documentation can be found at https://docs.csgofloat.com/#introduction

Comment: @platipus_on_fire yes I checked it. Unfortunately it only shows the ones that is being sold at csgofloat.com I need the ones being sold at steamcommunity.com . By the way ty for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to achieve your end goal (or what I understand from it). First, make sure that extension is installed, and check its exact location. Then you can do something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


import time as t

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')
chrome_options.add_argument('--load-extension=/home/user/.config/chromium/Default/Extensions/jjicbefpemnphinccgikpdaagjebbnhg/2.4.3_0') ## extension location on your filesystem

chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1280,720")

webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
url = 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/M4A4%20%7C%20Mainframe%20%28Minimal%20Wear%29'
browser.get(url)
t.sleep(2)
float_vals = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class="float-div"]')))
for f in float_vals:
    float_value = f.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class="csgofloat-itemfloat"]')
    paint_seed = f.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class="csgofloat-itemseed"]')
    print(float_value.text, paint_seed.text)
```

Result:

```
Float: 0.12355003505945 Paint Seed: 151
Float: 0.11305310577154 Paint Seed: 955
Float: 0.14578416943550 Paint Seed: 314
Float: 0.09940030425787 Paint Seed: 938
Float: 0.12989912927151 Paint Seed: 328
Float: 0.12652109563351 Paint Seed: 835
Float: 0.14991194009781 Paint Seed: 525
Float: 0.14711093902588 Paint Seed: 122
Float: 0.11300826072693 Paint Seed: 351
Float: 0.13550239801407 Paint Seed: 485
```

Selenium documentation: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a driver initialization, something like

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=options)
```

And opening a link, something like

```py
driver.get(url)
```