# How to find element by XPATH using variable Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I'm trying to parse some elements using XPATH

This is my python code:

```py
driver.get("http://watir.com/examples/shadow_dom.html")
shadow_host = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="shadow_host"]')
shadow_root1 = shadow_host.shadow_root
shadow_host1 = shadow_root1.find_element(By.XPATH, '/span')
```

selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: invalid locator

I know that I can use CSS Selectors, but I want to use it in case there aren't any CSS Selectors. Can you help me, how to write `shadow_host1` correctly using XPATH? Thanks

Comment: `'//span'` (double slash)?

Comment: Does not work:( Thanks for the answer @Yevhen Kuzmovych

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use XPATH locators with shadow root. You can use CSS LOCATORS instead (when on a Chrome/chromedriver setup), or alternatively (when using a Firefox/geckodriver setup) use javascript selectors (querySelector).

Comment: So how can I click on an option element?

    <csgofloat-page-size class="page-selector">
        #shadow-root (open)
            <select>
                <option value="10">
                    "10"
                </option>
            </select>
    </csgofloat-page-size>

Thank you very much for your answer

Comment: This is a different question. My answer addressed your original question. If you have more, post them as new questions.

Comment: @KraKoff_  -- just in case this answer is relevant to your follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73653766/inconsistently-getting-exception-has-occurred-javascriptexception-error-selen/73654695#73654695